# How can I use iOS's standard red number badges within my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, badge

I know that it's trivial to add a red number badge to an app's icon on the home screen. What's the best way to get a badge that looks like this within my app? There are some classes I've found online that can do this, such as [MKNumberBadgeView](http://www.claireware.com/blog_files/iphone_badge_view.html), but none that I've found look completely right. Facebook, for example, implements red badges within the app perfectly as far as I can see. Did they just build their own badges by trial and error? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Luke

Comment: Other posts suggest that the Three20 project has these badges (which would make sense, given the Facebook connection.) I didn't have any luck finding them. Does anybody know where I could find that code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Where do you want the badge? The standard badge can trivially be added to a `UITabBarItem` through the `badgeValue` property. It is documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarItem/badgeValue).

Comment: I'm hoping to stick the badge on a UIImageView, but ideally the badge would just be a view itself. This is a great suggestion and I might be able to use it if I can get the tab bar itself to be invisible, which I'm working on.

Comment: Did you have any success hiding the UITabBarItem while still showing the badge Luke?

Answer (score 6):

I am using this by Sascha Paulus -
http://www.spaulus.com/2011/04/custombadge-2-0-retina-ready-scalable-light-reflex/?lang=en

Which is a class that you can drop into your project, easy enough to customize for the appearance you are looking for. I had a slight issue with the placement of the number within the red badge so I shifted it slightly. Other than that, all good.

Answer (score 5):

This one looks 100% like the Apple one and it's also completely customizable: https://github.com/JaviSoto/JSBadgeView

Comment: does work as advertised. Integration via CocoaPods is trivial.

Comment: Do not use this with IOS 9+, it makes random crashes

Comment: If it's crashing, could you report it on the Github repo? I'd love to fix it.